# Change parameter from lambda function to lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I have extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> WithFieldLike<TResult>(
   this IQueryable<TResult> query,
   Func<TResult, string> field,
   string value)
{
   Expression<Func<TResult, bool>> expr = 
       trans => field(trans).Contains(value);
   return query.Where(expr);
}
```

I need change parameter field to type: Expression>. Will be something like.

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> WithFieldLike<TResult>(
   this IQueryable<TResult> query,
   Expression<Func<TResult, string>> field,
   string value)
{
   Expression<Func<TResult, bool>> expr = ???
   return query.Where(expr);
}
```

The call of this method is:

```
var query7 = query.WithFieldLike(trans => trans.DeviceModelNumber, "ber_3");
```

How should I build the "expr" in this case? Please help.

Comment: Please add the language to the tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deconstruct `field` and create a new expression, something like this:

```
var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<TResult, bool>> (
    Expression.Call (field.Body, typeof (string).GetMethod ("Contains"),
        Expression.Constant (value)), field.Parameters) ;
```

*(edited as per Maxs's refinement in comments)*

Comment: The point is that I can't build "Contains" expression. How to build "Equals" expression I know.

Comment: The final result is:
    var expr1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<TResult, bool>>(
                Expression.Call(field.Body, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), Expression.Constant(value))
                , field.Parameters);

Comment: Oh, sheesh. I didn't see Expression.Lambda<>() in `ildasm` ^ω^

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use `Expression.Invoke`; something like (untested):

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> WithFieldLike<TResult>(
   this IQueryable<TResult> query,
   Expression<Func<TResult, string>> field,
   string value)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TResult), "x");
    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<TResult, bool>>(
        Expression.Call(Expression.Invoke(field, param),
            "Contains", null, Expression.Constant(value)), param);

    return query.Where(expr);
}
```

(edit: fixed)

Comment: Thanks. This works too. But generates expression incompatible with ADO.NET Data Services call.

Comment: Gotta love the Law of Leaky Abstractions... it works with some but not all ;-p

Answer (score 1):

Use [Compile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362.aspx) to get the lambda back out:

```
Expression<Func<TResult, bool>> expr = 
   trans => field.Compile()(trans).Contains(value);
```

Edit: Whoops - my air compiler failed me. After compiling, you get the delegate. But, you still need to call it to get the string to call Contains.

Comment: Will be compilation error:
'System.Func<TResult,string>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and no extension method 'Contains' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Func<TResult,string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Maxs: Yeah - I kind of screwed up the whole "converting it to another expression" part. Point stands though - use Compile to get the lambda, and use it as normal.